# I'm still getting a Whitelabel error even though there is no error in my IDE

Tags: spring-boot

I'm still getting an error even though there is no error in my IDE

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
    @GetMapping
    public List<String> hello(){
        return List.of("hello", "world");
    }
}



 :: Spring Boot ::       (v3.0.0-SNAPSHOT)

2022-08-26T08:32:07.263+08:00  INFO 10580 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication using Java 17.0.4.1 on DESKTOP-53LAED9 with PID 10580 (C:\Users\Larty\Desktop\Programming Softwares\Springsss\demo\demo\target\classes started by Larty in C:\Users\Larty\Desktop\Programming Softwares\Springsss\demo\demo)
2022-08-26T08:32:07.276+08:00  INFO 10580 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-08-26T08:32:10.093+08:00  INFO 10580 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8060 (http)
2022-08-26T08:32:10.120+08:00  INFO 10580 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-08-26T08:32:10.121+08:00  INFO 10580 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.0.22]
2022-08-26T08:32:10.428+08:00  INFO 10580 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-08-26T08:32:10.434+08:00  INFO 10580 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3010 ms
2022-08-26T08:32:11.412+08:00  INFO 10580 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8060 (http) with context path ''
2022-08-26T08:32:11.435+08:00  INFO 10580 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 5.245 seconds (process running for 6.304)
```

More info that caused the error:
I change my port to 8060 cause I'm getting an error from 8080.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try specify a path:

```
@GetMapping("/")

// or this syntax
@GetMapping(path = "/")
```

If you want to have more control over request mapping, you can take a look at [`@RequestMapping`](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-requestmapping) annotation.

BTW, the port is running at 8060, accessing `http://localhost:8060` should return the list of Strings.